# C sorting explanation and trouble

Tags: c, sorting

I'm having trouble solving this problem. I'm supposed to sort then search an array (through binary search) but I'm having trouble in how to get the size of an array I think.

```
int binarySearch( int Arr[], int value)
{
  int low = 0;
  int high =sizeof(Arr)/sizeof(int);
  int mid = (low+high)/2;

  printf("%d\n",high);
  while (low <= high && Arr[mid] != value)
    {
      if( Arr[mid] < value)
        {
          low = mid+1;
        }
      else
        {
          high = mid-1;
        }
      mid = (low+high)/2;
    }
  if (low > high)
    {
      mid= -1;
    }
  return mid;
}


int main()
{
  BubbleSort( Array, 10);
  int pos = binarySearch(Array, 3);
  printf("The sorted array is: ");
  PrintArray( Array, 10);
  printf("\n");
  printf("Now lets look for number 3\n");
  printf("The number was located in space %d\n", pos);
  PrintArray( Array, 10);
}
```

But all I keep getting is:

```
 ./search
2 \\This is where I wanted to see what I was getting as the size of my array, 2???
The sorted array is: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Now lets look for number 3
The number was located in space -1
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Please not the declaring a parameter as `int Arr[]` does not have any special effect, the parameter is effectivly a pointer. So perhaps that's causing the confusion. You have to pass the length of the array to the function, there is no way of determining it's length it must be stored somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Using `sizeof` on an array which is a parameter to a function won't work as you expect.

When an array is passed to a function, it decays to a pointer to the first element of the array.

So this:

```
int binarySearch( int Arr[], int value)
```

Is the same as this:

```
int binarySearch( int *Arr, int value)
```

And `sizeof(Arr)` is the same as calling `sizeof(int *)`.

You need to pass the size of the array as a separate parameter to your function.

Answer (score 2):

What others have said about `sizeof` is correct... but there's even more information `binarySearch` needs to do its job:

```
int binarySearch( int Arr[], int low, int high, int value)
{
   int mid = (low+high)/2;
   ...
```

initially called as

```
binarySearch (Array, 0, 9, 3);
```

or better yet

```
binarySearch (Array, 0, SIZE-1, 3);
```

This is because binary search doesn't always start at 0 and doesn't always end at the end of the array.

Also note that `last`, the location of the last item, isn't the size of the array, but one less, because of C++'s 0-based counting.

For another look at how to do this, see this page, scroll down to the C++ section (which in this case has code that compiles fine as C):  http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Binary_search